# Hide component div from home page in joomla 3

Tags: php, css, joomla

I have a RocketTheme Affinity template that when it hides the component the wrapper stays untouched and i want it removed also.
I only want to disable it from the home page (id=101).
In the "index.php" the bellow code calls this:

```
<?php
echo $section_rows->render();
?>
```

The div name is "section-row3" in a file called "rt_sectionrows.php"
There are also css files called style6 and tempate.css files.

Conclusion:

How do I hide certain div and class from homepage?

Comment: $('.section-row3').hide() use jquery

Comment: How can i assign that code to effect my homepage only? Home page id is 101

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<?php
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu = $app->getMenu();
if ($menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault()) {
    ?>
<script type="text/javascript">jQuery(document).ready(function(){   
jQuery('.section-row3').hide()
});</script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Add this code at the bottom of your home page. It hide that div.

Hope it helps.

Comment: It did not but i think that the file structure is responsible for that.

Comment: It did not but i think that the file structure is responsible for that. There is index.php file that uses
<?php
echo $section_rows->render();
?> to call the function from the file rt_sectionrows.php in which there is the code for the blocks, rows, etc.How can i assign the code you added above in a specific menu item with id 101?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just do this with some CSS.

Go into the Joomla! Administrator, Menus, Select the menu which contains your homepage menu item and then edit it.

In the menu item, select 'Page Display'. At the bottom you will see: Page Class.

Add a space and type: homep

Then add:

```
.homep .section-row3 {display: none !important;}
```

To your Rocket Theme Custom CSS or LESS file.
Then that will just hide it with CSS, we have specified !important, so it takes priority.

Comment: What if i include this line into first lines of existing template.css or style6.css files?

Comment: You can but that's bad practice as it will be lost when you update the template. Place it in a custom made template-custom.less in the less directory of the rocket theme template and it will be compiled into the templates.css file.